# c# method parameters API design

Tags: c#, parameters, methods, arguments

I want to discuss API method design.

We are building a c# dll that will be responsible of some machine actions (like open door, close door etc.) I want to expose to the client one function (let's call it "**doAction(parameters...)**"). This function will get one parameter, and the parameter is the type of the action (an argument).

My question is: what is the best way to design the argument and if you can give me links to examples. It can be aclass of const. strings or class of enums, anything that can be professionally designed and yet easy to use.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you only want one method? It seems more natural to have methods like `OpenDoor(int doorNum); CloseDoor(int doorNum, bool slam); OpenClosedOrAjar GetDoorState(int doorNum);`

Comment: Forgot to tell. this is my design requirements.

Comment: why is it in your design requirements?

Comment: its the customer that i develop the dll for him. that's the way they working.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Action Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)

Other than that, you might want to implement an `IAction` [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28VS.80%29.aspx) with a `DoAction` Method.

So, something like

```
interface IAction
{
    void DoMethod();
}
```

and

```
public class OpenDoor : IAction
{
    public void DoMethod()
    {
        //Open the door
    }
}
```

Comment: I looked in the article you suggested. It's an interesting method but I don't see how can it help me.

Comment: About the interface, can you be give more details? Thanks.

Comment: You can pass an Class impelementing an Interface to the method. So they all implement the same methods, but do what they are meant to do. This will allow you to make this Database/XMl driven. You need to show us a little bit more about the calling Method, and howyou are deciding which Action to do...

Answer (score 1):

It seems more natural to expose each of these as a separate method, as in:

```
public class Machine
{
    public void OpenDoor();
    public void CloseDoor();
    // other methods
}
```

This would be used as follows:

```
Machine NewMachine = new Machine();
NewMachine.OpenDoor();
NewMachine.CloseDoor();
```

That code is very readable.

However, if you're really interested in doing it all from one method, then an enumerated value can suffice:

```
public class Machine
{
    public enum Action
    {
        OpenDoor,
        CloseDoor,
        // other values
    }

    public void DoAction(Action ActionToDo)
    {
        switch(ActionToDo)
        {
            case OpenDoor:
                // open the door
                break;
            case CloseDoor:
                // close the door
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, it's a good example. thanks.